# Laravel Passport: Are API's tokens stored on the server, and where?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, token, laravel-passport

I tried to find where the token returned by the method `$user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;` is stored on the database but I can't seem to find it. Is it stored in the server in the first place? If so, where?

If it's not stored on the server because it's self-contained, why did Laravel's developers put `$table->rememberToken();` in the default `create_users_table.php` migration? What's the purpose of the column `remember_token`?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess you could say that *some* part of the token is stored in the database.

The token returned is [JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction/) (JSON Web Token). Encoded in it is information about the token, like its expiration time, the algorithm used to hash it, the token scopes and its ID (in the payload it's named `jti`). That ID is what's stored in the `oauth_access_tokens` table.

In this method in the `\Laravel\Passport\PersonalAccessTokenFactory::findAccessToken` class you can see how Laravel is checking if the token is in the database:

```
 /**
 * Get the access token instance for the parsed response.
 *
 * @param  array  $response
 * @return Token
 */
protected function findAccessToken(array $response)
{
    return $this->tokens->find(
        $this->jwt->parse($response['access_token'])->getClaim('jti')
    );
}
```

If you get a valid token and paste it in [this online tool](https://jwt.io/) you will see the structure of it. Here's how it looks:

[image: screenshot of the parsed token]

Now, knowing the expected format of the payload, if you play around a bit with this information and the data you have in your `oauth_access_tokens` (id, scope, creation and expiration date) you should be able to create a valid token.

Comment: Is it good practice to use only token id to authorize? We don't need expiration date and the scope is being checked server side.

Comment: Great Answer! Is there a way to manually encode 'access_token' from oauth_access_tokens.id as same as passport do?

Comment: nice! was wondering how passport is able to identify the user with the `access_token`, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Remember token in user table is for "Remember Me" when you log in on web. 
[Laravel: What is “remember_token” in the “users” DB table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262351/laravel-what-is-remember-token-in-the-users-db-table?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

If you use passport and create API you can find token id in oauth_access_tokens in database.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not exactly the same token. The `id` in the `oauth_access_tokens` table is way smaller than what is returned by `$user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;`.

Answer (score 1):

No, the access token value is not stored anywhere. If you lose it, it's gone. You'll need to regenerate a new token.

The `rememeber_token` field is for the "Remember Me" functionality for normal web authentication. It is not related to Passport API authentication at all.

Comment: wondering how it works if the actual token is not saved anywhere in the db .. tried searching the system files but couldn't find anything