# Where are Laravel Passport access tokens stored?

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

When I request an access token at `oauth/token` using the password grant, I get a token back. However this token is the same every time and doesn't match any token in the database. Where are these tokens stored? And how can I use this token to retrieve my user data in an AJAX call?

Comment: Please take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50254237/laravel-passport-are-apis-tokens-stored-on-the-server-and-where)

Answer (score 3):

After installing passport. you need to run command `php artisan migrate`.
this command will create 4 tables.

- `oauth_access_tokens`
- `oauth_auth_codes`
- `oauth_personal_access_clients`
- `oauth_refresh_tokens`

PASSPORT ACCESS TOKENS ARE STORED IN `oauth_access_tokens` table.
in this table `id` column is used to store token.

Answer (score 0):

The token generated by oauth server is unique and you have to store it somewhere like cookies or user table. You can pass the access_token through authorization header.

Ajax call :

```
var token = "Your access_token";
$.ajax({
url:"someurl.com/api/auth/getuser",
dataType: 'json',
headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
},
success: function(data, status) {
   return console.log("The returned data", data);
}
});
```